# What is wrong with a HttpBasicAuthenticator

Tags: restsharp

I am trying to use a RestSharp coding sample in order to connect to MailGun. In the code below, please see:

```
client.Authenticator = new HttpBasicAuthenticator("XXX","key-yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy");
```

What is wrong with the `HttpBasicAuthenticator`? VisualStudio says:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line Error  CS0246  The type or
>   namespace name 'HttpBasicAuthenticator' could not be found (are you
>   missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)  xTest_MailGun

Note: Visual Studio2015 Community; RestSharp 105.2.3

This is the code:

```
RestClient client = new RestClient();
client.BaseUrl = new Uri("https://api.mailgun.net/v3");   
client.Authenticator =   new HttpBasicAuthenticator("XXX","key-yyyyyyyyyy");  
RestRequest request = new RestRequest();
```

Answer (score 7):

Authenticators are in a different namespace than RestClient, you're likely just missing a `using` statement at the top. Do you have this?

```
using RestSharp;
```

Add this right below it:

```
using RestSharp.Authenticators;
```

Comment: Thank you!
For some reason as in way too many C# documented examples it is always missing what to import to get some method or property referenced. Most annoying when it is not mentioned anywhere in the official documentation.